# Regex somente na primeira ocorrência

Tags: regex, sublime-text

Estou usando o sublime e gostaria de fazer um replace em massa. Meus textos estão neste padrão:

`ABC ("Teste regex`

Gostaria de remover o espaço após o *ABC* e deve ficar assim:

`ABC("Teste regex`

Como ficaria a regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem simples.

Na busca use a seguinte regex: `(ABC)\s`.

Onde está entre parênteses é o conteúdo que vai permanecer e o restante fora do grupo é o que vai ser apagado.

No conteúdo para fazer o replace, use `$1`.

Então basicamente estamos pegando tudo que foi encontrado na regex "ABC " e substituindo pelo conteúdo do primeiro grupo da regex que é "ABC".

> $1 indica que você está pegando tudo que foi encontrado no primeiro grupo da regex, os parênteses definem um grupo.

**Veja funcionando no** [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3ipnp)

Lembrando que o `\s` pega espaços, quebra de linha, tabs, etc. Caso queira pegar somente o espaço, você pode colocar um espaço em branco no final.

Comment: Pode exemplificar ? Essa parte do $1 que não consigo.

Comment: @Douglas Editei, vê se ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado...funcionou....pra mim ficou assim: `([A-Z]{3})\s`

Comment: @Douglas Também vai funcionar, mas você vai pegar qualquer conteúdo com 3 letras seguido de um espaço. Eu fiz para pegar exatamente ABC. Vlw

Comment: Rapaz, sua explicação foi genial..me confundia com essa história de grupos...então eles ficam entre parênteses...show.

Answer (score 0):

Se sua intenção é remover um ou mais espaços antes de um parênteses você pode fazer assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- O \s serve para capturar espaços, tabs, quebras de linha, etc.
- O * logo após significa que esse espaço pode ocorrer nenhuma ou
  várias vezes.
- E por fim o ( representa a abertura do parênteses, mas como esse é um caractere especial para a regex temos que adicionar a barra antes para escapar.

  Find: \s*(

  Replace: (

Asism é possível pegar vários tipos de situação:
[image: Screenshot resultado]